# Add custom solution to shopify customize panel?

Tags: shopify

Client asked me to make hover effect on Add To Cart button but only for Single product, i have managed to do that via css, but now he instructed me that he want that solution implemented inside his Customize Panel so that he can change the color of that product himself.

Any help would be appreciated here, since i don't even know where to start, or how that is supposed to look.

For start i would like to know weather this is possible or not?

Comment: Please share some code you have used to make it work. Also what is customization panel? Also how many variants are present in a product? Show an example of what you have done. Share whatever you think could be necessary, only then you can get a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is information on "Theme Settings". Shopify sometimes refers to this as the [Storefront Editor](https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/storefront-editor)

A tutorial is here: http://www.tetchi.ca/shopify-theme-from-scratch-part-14/

You're going to have to understand some of that and try some things before we can be of much further help

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution on how to add this based on your tutorial links, now that I see it looks pretty simple...but in case someone get stuck on a similar problem.

I have achieved this with following 3 steps:

1: First adding unique ID to every button based on the product page, in file that is generating every product page:

```
id="atc_single_product-{{ product.id }}"
```

2: For generating option in Customize Panel, added following inside Config file "settings_schema.json":

```
  {
    "type": "color",
    "id": "atc_single_product-7214350529",
    "label": "Montreal #9",
    "default": "#333333"
  },
```

3. Added some basic HTML for hover effect that will call to action and combine both step 1 and 2 and once hovered :

   ```
   #atc_single_product-7214350529:hover, input#atc_single_product-7214350529[type="submit"]:hover, input#atc_single_product-7214350529[type="button"]:hover 
       {
         background: {{ settings.atc_single_product-7214350529 }};
         border-color: {{ settings.atc_single_product-7214350529 }};
         outline: none;
       }
   ```

End Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2RiG.png

Maybe it doesn't look pretty, but it hey it works. Thanks!